# YAML anchors issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, yaml, settingslogic

Here is the tutorial I'm following: http://rhnh.net/2011/01/31/yaml-tutorial

I'm using the SettingsLogic gem: https://github.com/binarylogic/settingslogic

And every config file used by Settings logic works fine, but if I use the same tactics on database.yml or thinking_sphinx.yml it will not work.

Comment: what tactics? could you give example files which work, and which don't work?

Comment: We can't see your monitor, so we have no idea what your code looks like. Include a minimal example, with sample input and expected output.

Comment: Sorry. Yes I understand. I'm testing right now.

Comment: Sorry guys for disturbing. I don't know why it was happen. Looks like some sort of wrong environment config or line indenting. I've tested sphinx and now it works fine. I'll test other yml files and reopen if problem occurs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My bad I didn't specified full stack info.

I'm using passenger. But I missed directive `RailsEnv` in apache config file.

http://www.modrails.com/documentation/Users%20guide%20Apache.html#rails_env

By default, passenger loads production environment.

Setting `RailsEnv staging` solved my problem. And now correct settings picked.